# Python MysqlDB кодировка

Tags: mysql, python

Помогите разобраться с проблемой кодировок (русский язык) при считывании данных из MySQL. Mysql-5.5, Python 2.7.10, MySQLDB 1.2.4b4

Вывод скрипта:

```
[(<type 'int'>, u'\ufeff\u0410\u0434\u044b\u0433\u0435\u044f', <type 'unicode'>)]
```

Хотелось бы вместо u'\ufeff\u0410\u0434\u044b\u0433\u0435\u044f' получить читабельный текст.

Сам скрипт:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8-*-
import MySQLdb

conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="192.168.0.14", user="root", passwd="rfW15stoWn", db="infinity", charset='utf8', use_unicode = True)
cur = conn.cursor()

query = 'SELECT `region`, `code` FROM `code_regions`'
cur.execute(query)
code = []
for row in cur:
    code.append((type(len(row[1])), row[0], type(row[1])))

print(code)
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

В my.cnf прописано:

```
[client]
default-character-set   = utf8

[mysqld]
skip-character-set-client-handshake
collation-server        = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect            = 'SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server    = utf8
character_set_client    = utf8
```

Загрузка данных при таких настройка происходит нормально. Отображение в Mysql через WorkBench тоже корректно.

Comment: Кодировка мускула тут не причем. Вы же на принт выводите кортеж, и данные в этом случае пишуться ASCII строковым представлением юникода. Выводите нужную строку в нужной кодировке. print code[1].encode("utf8")

Comment: Хочется получать данные после SELECT в типе string, а не в unicode

Comment: @АнтонВоробьв Вы не засунете UTF8 строку в string в python2.x. Точнее, засунете, но поимеете от этого только головную боль. `print code[0][1]` должно в консоль выводить нормально в Вашем случае.

Comment: print code[1] отлично выводится

Comment: @АнтонВоробьв, в чем собственно проблема? Вы же сами полученные из селекта стринги запихали в список кортежей и вывели последний на принт, а не стринги, как того хотите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вывод осуществлять так:

```
print(code[0][1].encode("utf8"))
```

Вот код целиком:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8-*-
import MySQLdb

conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="192.168.0.14", user="root", passwd="rfW15stoWn", db="infinity", charset='utf8', use_unicode = True)
cur = conn.cursor()

query = 'SELECT `region`, `code` FROM `code_regions`'
cur.execute(query)
code = []
for row in cur:
    code.append((type(len(row[1])), row[0], type(row[1])))

print(code[0][1].encode("utf8"))
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: На будущее, убирайте пароли из кода)))